# Adding all matching values of objects in an array (Javascript) (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### What I'm Using

- Angular 5
- AngularFire5
- Firebase & Firestore

### What I'm Trying to Achieve

I am trying to cycles through all of the items in an array, which holds objects. If a certain value in the object matches the same value in the other object, then it will add another value together.

**Example:**

Start With:

```
mapData = [{"countryCode":"US", "clicks": 5}, {"countryCode":"CAN", "clicks": 9}, {"countryCode":"US", "clicks": 6}]
```

or

```
mapData = [["US", 5], ["CAN", 9], ["US", 6]]
```

End With:

```
mapDataResults = {
    "US": {
        "usage": 11,
        "fillKey": "tens"
    },
    "CAN": {
        "usage": 9,
        "fillKey": "ones"
    },
}
```

### Where I'm Stuck

I have no idea on how to search and match through the different object values in the array. Additonally, I would need to figure out how to reorganize how the data is returned, instead of an array it would need to be in a JSON format. Finally, and I think I might be able to figure this out myself, if I can get help with the other parts, but for there to be an additonal value added "fillKey" based on how large the number of clicks (or *usage*) were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first collection is an array of arrays:

```
let entries = [["US", 5], ["CAN", 9],["US", 6]];

function getMostSigDigitName(number) {
    switch(Math.floor(number).toString().length) {
        case 1: return 'ones';
        case 2: return 'tens';
    }
}

function consolidateAndEmit(a) {
    let result = {};
    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        let key = a[i][0];
        let val = a[i][1];
        if(result[key]) {//exists, so update
            result[key].usage += val;
        }
        else {//does not exist, so add 
            result[key] = { usage: val};
        }
        result[key].fillKey = getMostSigDigitName(result[key].usage);
    }
    return result;
}

consolidateAndEmit(entries);
```

Comment: I want to just make sure you understood what I was asking, I am hoping for mapData to look like mapDataResults. I updated the question for it to make more sense

Comment: Is mapData an array of arrays or an array of objects?

Comment: I just updated my question even more to make more sense. I realized it didnt make sense

Comment: So this function will search through all of the country codes (US, CAN, ETC) if there is any match, it will add those numbers together and then add the pair to an object?

I just wanna make sure I understand everything that is happening!

Comment: Yes, this will do what you need.

Comment: Awesome! Now the last thing, can i return entries as the consolidated form? right now I would need to call consolidateAndEmit(entries) inorder for the data to be correct

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. consolidateAndEmit(entries); is returning the new object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash), this might be a good one:

```
mapData = [{"US", 5}, {"CAN", 9},{"US", 6}];
```

and then `_.sumBy(mapData, 'US')` or `_.sumBy(mapData, "CAN")`

All you need to do is map the response to an object. I have given the flow to get the sum and it gets added if `mapData` array has extra data containing "US" or "CAN".

Comment: So if I was doing this for every country in the world, I would need to do an or for all 195 country codes?

Comment: You can create a country list array and map then in sumBy. That way you only have one line of code.